# Variables "privadas" en proyecto repositado

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-app-engine, gitlab-ci

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto Java con [GAE](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/) y GitLab. En dicho proyecto tengo una clase no repositada con variables que no me gustaría que fueran "publicas" (sus valores son identificadores y claves).

En estos momentos estoy intentando meter integración continua, con el objetivo de cuando se actualicen ciertas ramas, se despliegue de forma automática el proyecto. El problema le tengo en la clase anterior, al no estar en GitLab da errores de compilación.

¿Existe alguna manera de sacar los valores de las variables al repositorio (manteniendo su privacidada los administradores de GitLab o del proyecto GAE) y que se puedan utilizar en el proyecto Java?

EDIT 1:
Como solución temporal he optado por guardxar en BBDD los secretos y en un fichero. En caso de no encontrarlos en BBDD los cogería de un fichero. La primera subida a GAE la realizo desde el propio IDE (en mi caso eclipse) para que grabe dichos secretos en BBDD. Las siguientes subidas que serán con la Integracion continua el fichero no viaja por no estar repositado y cogera la información directamente de BBDD.

Comment: ¿Te has planteado añadir esos identificadores y claves que necesita el proyecto en otro tipo de fichero, como XML, JSON, etc.?

Comment: No pasaría lo mismo, no podría subirlo al repositorio. ¿Cómo los podría luego recuperar desde GAE?

Comment: ni idea. El problema que veo es añadir esos valores que no deben estar en el repo a una clase, que si es parte del proyecto. En el momento que compiles ese proyecto sin esa clase: error. No tendrías el programa al completo, por eso habría que buscar una alternativa, para evitar el error en la compilación.

Comment: @Orici me he basado en tu propuesta para realizar una posible solución, no se si es la más correcta en estos casos (de ahí que deje la pregunta sin respuesta fija) pero por ahora funciona. He editado el mensaje inicial con dicha solución en el EDIT 1.

Comment: Puede haber distintas soluciones a un mismo problema. Guardar variables de configuración en base de datos es un método válido y habitual, siempre que estas NO contengan datos sensibles, ya que en algún momento se puede sufrir un acceso no deseado (por ello no se deben guardar contraseñas sin encriptar).
Muchos frameworks, y consecuentemente aplicaciones, usan un fichero donde se almacenan datos sensibles como texto plano, claves para encriptar, datos de acceso a la BD, etc. Este fichero no se guarda en el repositorio, pero se debe desplegar con la aplicación, de forma automática o manual.